# What's the use of radios?

Tags: dying-light

I just started the game last night, so I haven't gone too far in yet. From the start of the game I can see radios lying around, but they don't seem to do much. Does turning them on attract zombies? Do they serve any function? Please explain, but if they are used in quests please don't tell me how they are used in-quest. Thanks!

Comment: I don't really remember seeing radios lying around... It's been a long time since I've played though. If you can turn them on, I would assume they attract zombies... Otherwise I would just expect them to be salvageable for parts or something.

Comment: No, they're not items in your inventory, they lie around in the world for you to interact with. There's one right in the room when you start the game. You can only turn them on or off

Comment: I never suggested you could take them. I played a bit yesterday but didn't find one (admittedly I wasn't really looking...). If I remember, I'll try to find one out in the world.

Answer (score 1):

The radios are purely cosmetic and for ambiance. You can turn them on/off if you want to hear/not hear the music or noise that they play. I personally turn them off because it gets annoying but in terms of actual gameplay; they affect no quests and do not attract zombies whatsoever.

They also tend to be in safe zones or places where zombies cannot even get to you anyway.